# Pre-image of Borel sets is closed under complements

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable defined on some sample space $\Omega$. Consider the collection $\mathcal{B}_X = \lbrace X^{-1}(A) : A\in \mathcal B (\mathbb R) \rbrace$, where $\mathcal B (\mathbb R)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$.

My question: How does one show that $\mathcal B_X$ is closed under complements?

$\mathcal B (\mathbb R)$ is of course closed under complements, so if $X^{-1}(A) \in  \mathcal{B}_X $, then $X^{-1}(A^c) \in  \mathcal{B}_X $. But this doesn't imply, I assume, that $X^{-1}(A^c) = \Omega \setminus X^{-1}(A)$. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: As soon as you have proved your assumption you are ready. Do you agree on that?

Comment: @drhab you mean $X$ is an rv with respect to $\mathcal{B}_X$?

Comment: No, I mean the assumption that $X^{-1}(A^c)=X^{-1}(A)^c$. It is correct.

Comment: @drhab yes, but I don't quite see why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B\in\mathcal B_{X}$ then $B=X^{-1}(A)$ for some $A\in\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$. Then also $A^c\in\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}$ and consequently $B^c=X^{-1}(A)^c=X^{-1}(A^c)\in\mathcal B_X$. This shows that $\mathcal B_{X}$ is closed under complements.

---

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a function and $A\subseteq Y$ then $x\in f^{-1}(A)\iff f(x)\in A$. This is purely based on the definition of $f^{-1}(A)$:$$f^{-1}(A):=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in A\}$$
So the following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f^{-1}(A^c)$
- $f(x)\in A^c$
- $f(x)\notin A$
- $x\notin f^{-1}(A)$
- $x\in f^{-1}(A)^c$

The equivalence of the first and last statement tells us that: $$f^{-1}(A^c)=f^{-1}(A)^c$$